# Understanding SAGA Watershed Segmentation in QGIS: Error 1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, saga, image-segmentation, error-1

I am trying to run a watershed segmentation using the SAGA plugin in QGIS.  Unfortunately, every time I have tried to run this on a specific file QGIS freezes. The log output reports the following:

[image]

What is particularly odd about this is that it worked on a similar file just a few hours prior. The only difference is that the image it keeps failing on is a DSM generated by BCAL lidar tools and the image that was successful was a DSM generated by ENVI lidar.

I also ran the watershed segmentation using the standalone SAGA on the file that kept failing and it was completed successfully.

Comment: I use this algorithm in linux and windows without problem through qgis processing modeler... as you can see from the message saga miss a gdal_MrSID.dll btw probably is a saga version problem as stated in the answers below

Answer (score 1):

Which SAGA version are you using? I've found [this](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11432) QGIS bug report mentioning the same error as yours. The solution there was provided by Giovanni Manghi in the end of the post:

> *saga 2.0.8 compatibility check is not enabled.*
>
> The fact you see this option suggest me that you have an old version of 'Processing'  masking the latest one shipped with qgis 2.8, because it does not exist anymore.
> Check inside .qgis/python/plugins
> If you have a "processing" folder you must delete it. Then restart qgis.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be causing the problem here. One notable difference between layers that are successful and those that crash during segmentation is that the successful layers use WGS 84 (ESPG:4326), while the layers that crash are in OR North State Plane (ESPG:2838).

Comment: I see. I think you should update your question with this information; it might help getting more answers. @Jamie.